# Set multiple parameters in body for http.client.HTTPConncetion.request

Tags: python, http

Having the following request

```py
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("mydomain.com")
    body = "param1=value1 param2=value2" #<== fails
    headers = {
    'Some-type': 'header value'
    }

    #make the request
    conn.request("POST", "/api_call", body, headers)
```

Ill need to parse multiple parameters in the `body`, but I cannot figure out how to seperate them.

Looking in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpconnection-objects) the body can be either a string, byte or iterable. I have tried different ways of creating a string e.g `"param1=value1 param2=value2"` or `"param1=value1;param2=value2"`. I have also tried setting it as a tuple i.e `("param1","value1","param2","value2")` but that does not work.

Note, it has to be the `http` library thus I cannot switch to `requests`

Answer (score 0):

Just as I posted the question, I tried with

```py
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("mydomain.com")
    body = r"param1=value1&param2=value2" #<== use & to seperate parameters
    headers = {
    'Some-type': 'header value'
    }

    #make the request
    conn.request("POST", "/api_call", body, headers)
```

which solved it